# NumberFormatException when fetching Double from DynamoDB in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb, type-conversion, aws-sdk

I am developing a Spring Boot application where I use AWS SDK for fetching data from DynamoDB. I am running into the problem where DynamoDB Type converter is attempting to parse a `Double` as an `Integer`, resulting in a `NumberFormatException`.

My entity class is as follows:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "my_table")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @Getter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
    private MyKey myKey;
    
    // Other attributes...
    
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "overall_energy")
    @DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.DynamoDBAttributeType.N)
    private Double overallEnergy;
    
    // Other attributes...

}
```

The data I am trying to fetch from DynamoDB looks like this:

```
{
  "overall_energy": {
    "N":  "29985.689834184945"
  }
}
```

However, when I attempt to fetch this data, I get a `NumberFormatException`:

```
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "29985.689834184945"
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67) ~[na:na]
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668) ~[na:na]
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:999) ~[na:na]
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$ToInteger$2.convert(StandardTypeConverters.java:773) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.454.jar!/:na]
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$ToInteger$2.convert(StandardTypeConverters.java:770) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.454.jar!/:na]
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$1.unconvert(StandardTypeConverters.java:75) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.454.jar!/:na]
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$DelegateConverter.unconvert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:109) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.454.jar!/:na]
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$NullSafeConverter.unconvert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:128) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.454.jar!/:na]
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$ExtendedConverter.unconvert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:88) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.454.jar!/:na]
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:146) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.454.jar!/:na]
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.unconvertAndSet(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:164) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.454.jar!/:na]
Jun  9 22:20:39 ip-10-55-167-190 web: at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:267) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.454.jar!/:na]
```

It seems the SDK is attempting to parse the `Double` as an `Integer`, but I don't understand why this is happening. I am using version 1.12.454 of the AWS SDK.

All references to `overallEnergy` in my codebase treat it as a `Double`.

I tried the following steps to solve it:

1. **Created a Custom Converter (`StringToDoubleTypeConverter`)**

   Expectation: I expected that by explicitly converting the string from the database to a double in Java using my own converter, it would resolve the issue.

   Result: This approach did not work. The **`NumberFormatException`** was still being thrown.
2. **Removed Explicit Type Conversion Annotations**

   Expectation: I thought perhaps the issue was with the explicit type conversion annotations, so I removed them to let the DynamoDBMapper handle the conversion implicitly.

   Result: The issue was not resolved. The **`NumberFormatException`** persisted.
3. **Modified the `overall_energy` Value in DynamoDB Record**

   Expectation: Suspecting that the issue might be related to the size of the number or the precision, I changed the value of **`overall_energy`** in the DynamoDB record to only have two decimal places.

   Result: This did not resolve the issue. The **`NumberFormatException`** was still being thrown.
4. **Changed `overall_energy` to an Integer Value**

   Expectation: I changed the value of **`overall_energy`** in the DynamoDB record to an integer value by removing the decimal values. This was a test to see if the issue was solely related to handling decimal values.

   Result: This change worked in the sense that the **`NumberFormatException`** was not thrown and the number was parsed correctly. However, the value was treated as an integer and not a double, which does not meet the needs of my application. The application requires this field to be treated as a **`double`** value.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I could resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Could there be a locale problem? Could something expect to use a something other than a `.` for a decimal point? What if, for example, you attempt to parse "29985,689834184945" ?

Comment: I made a test with *localstack* and the double conversion worked, so I think the error is somehow hidden.
I would try to remove the Spring Data annotation on the composite key `myKey` and decompose the same, inside the entity, in two fields:
1. annotated with `@DynamoDBHashKey`
2. annotated with `@DynamoDBRangeKey`
See if it helps